# how to get iframe content mouseover event using Jquery

Tags: events, iframe

I'm stuck in iframe,

**My issue :** i'm not getting iframe content mouseover event

**how to get iframe content mouseover event by using Jquery ?**

Please let me know quickly if u have solution for this

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail? Are the iframe's contents on the same domain as the surrounding page? Do you control the iframed page?

Comment: For example :

<iframe src="https://www.tutorialspoint.com/" width="100%" height="500" id="demo" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" >
            </iframe>


so when i click on iframe content so i didn't get any event

Comment: Yup, that's because the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) prevents you from interacting with documents that don't belong to you.